# ThreeJs EventHandling Hierarchies

Tags: javascript, three.js, event-handling, dom-events

I have many instantiated objects which all require their own handling of a specific event.

I have a class foo:

```
export default class Foo(){
    constructor(eventManager){//reference to an event manager class
       eventManager.eventPool.push(this.eventHandler)
       this.someProperty = 'hello world'
    }
    eventHandler(e){
       // logic to handle passed in event args
       console.log(this.someProperty) //any property I access is undefined, no matter what I try
    }
```

}

I have a static event handling class

```
export default class EventManager(){
  constructor(){
     this.eventPool = []
     window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this), false)
  }
  onMouseMove(e){
    if(this.eventPool.length > 0){
      for(let i=0;i<this.eventPool.length; ++i){
        this.eventPool[i](e)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when I call the eventHandler of a class and access its properties, they are undefined, I tried to bind the eventHandler to the class but that didn't work either. I'm not sure how the references are being handled since java-scripts not statically typed (natively)

this is being used in the context of threejs to abstract event handling away to be able to handle user input in various different ways on mesh's/other intractable items in the scene. I am aware of three.js's EventDispatcher but it doesn't give me enough control of the event hierarchy, I plan to make complicated event chains that I would like to be all neatly handled in a class that would not require editing source code.

**How do I allow own objects eventHandlers to be called from a class managing all the objects function references? on a certain event?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled on the answer whilst reading some of three's source code and found a similar pattern...

While the solution was to bind the function to the instance as I tried before, it had to actually be done WHEN YOU PASS IT INTO THE ARRAY, not before, or after. With the example provided it would look like this....

```
export default class Foo(){
    constructor(eventManager){//reference to an event manager class
       eventManager.eventPool.push(this.eventHandler.bind(this))//bind the method while we pass it in
       this.someProperty = 'hello world'
    }
    eventHandler(e){ 
       console.log(this.someProperty) //now the function refrence will correctly access the instances properties
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is

```
for(let evenHandler in this.eventPool)
```

`this.eventPool` is an array, `for let eventHandler in` will only get the `key` or `index` of the array, rather than the element `value`. Try `for let eventHandler of` or `let eventHandlerValue = this.eventPool[eventHandler]`.

Comment: Still has that problem, thank you for pointing that out, I rushed the question code. In my actual code I do use an index https://imgur.com/a/gwFgqNL I still get this undefined behavior on the actual classes. Let me update the question...

Comment: Right. Then I suggest add `debugger;` after `eventManager.eventPool.push(this.eventHandler)` to see what happened. By the way, I never used the syntax like `class x() {}`, generally it is like `class x {}`, I doubt whether that affects. Can you give any reference of this usage, please?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved the problem, it was a binding issue, more specifically... an issue of how javascript handles function references from object references. Javascript sure has some wacky quirks to it.